# Find array accesses in a basic block

Tags: llvm

How can I check whether there are array accesses in a basic block?

For example, I want to find  a[i] in the following example.

Eg:

```
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                  a[i]=a[i+1]+i;
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this at the LLVM level, as opposed to Clang level? I.e. if you're analyzing C code you are better off looking at the AST Clang generates

Answer (score 1):

Array accesses are modeled by `getelementptr` instructions.
So you could iterate over the Basic Block with something like:

```
for (BasicBlock::iterator i = blk->begin(), e = blk->end(); i != e; ++i) {
  if(isa<GetElementPtrInst>(i)) {
    // process it here
  }
}
```

Comment: Array accesses are not the only things modeled by GEPs though. Pointer dereferncing is too. So is struct member access. So you need to be careful here

Comment: Right, but the question is rather vague, so it's at least a good start!

Comment: See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682705/identify-array-type-in-ir

Comment: even structure are accessed in similar way ?? how to differentiate it ??

Comment: Yes, structure accesses are done in the same way. You could look at the type that the GEP is operating on.